# All Fields not working on Lookup Search

Tags: custom-object, lookup, search

I have Policy, Plan and Company custom objects where Company 1:N Plan 1:N Policy through lookup relationships.

When creating a new Policy I click on lookup Plan, then I attempt to search by the Company name with All Fields selected but no results are retrieved. This is strange since it works in another org.

So far I've checked that both orgs have enabled Enhanced Search, and all 3 objects have a tab although only Policy tab is displayed by default.

What am I missing? thanks

Comment: Did you check if the profile has access to the objects itself. go to the user profile and in the custom object CRUD settings check if the profile has atleast read access to plan and company objects.

Comment: In both orgs I'm using system admin and just to be sure, yes all three objects have CRUD access

Comment: did you check if there are there lookup filters

Comment: Plan and Company are selected in Plan/Search Layouts/Lookup Filter Fields

Comment: can you come here: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4337/salesforce

Comment: @rao I didn't find a way to tag you for helping me with the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm realizing that the org where this is working has a text field in Plan that is compounded of Company name and Plan name (this compounded field is to avoid Plan dupes in same Company). And the org where this is not working has the compounded field of Company ID and Plan Name, thus company name ain't searchable.

And is understandable that in one org it does work because the company name is embedded in a text field of Plan while on the other org it is the company Id not the name which is embedded.

Thanks to @rao for helping me bounce ideas to figure this out

Comment: Thats ok :), happy I learnt something new.